# Solving inequalities with the same variable on both sides and 2 possible cases

Tags: inequality

I have tried solving the following inequality, and I had found a flaw in my work that I, unfortunately, can't spot.

Here's the inequality:

$\frac{1}{x} > x$

I am aware that I have to consider that $x$ can be positive or negative. So, I considered those two cases separately and proceeded like so:

**Case $x > 0$**

 $0 > x^2 - 1$

 $0 > (x - 1)(x + 1)$

 $x<1$ and $x<-1$

 Thus, I concluded that $1>x>0$

**Case $x < 0$**

 $1<x^2$

 $0<x^2-1$

 $0<(x-1)(x+1)$

 $x>1$ and $x>-1$

 Thus, I concluded that $1>x>-1$

 However, this is wrong!
Could someone please walk me through the procedure one needs to take when solving inequalities of that type

I know that this might appear like a silly question, however, I am really unsure where my mistake is. **Any help would be appreciated!**

Comment: You have shown that the inequality holds for all $0<x<1$. Now for $x<0$ it is $$0<(x-1)(x+1)$$ which is true for all $x<-1$ because then both terms are $<0$ and the product is $>0$. Also, it is wrong for $-1<x<0$ because then $x+1>0$ and $x-1<0$. So the final solution is $$\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{0<x<1\text{ or }-1>x}$$

Comment: Thank you. I am just a little unsure how you got $−1>x$ from $0<(x−1)(x+1)$. Could you please explain it a little further? Because doesn't this inequality simply mean that: $1<x$ and $-1<x$?

Comment: No, it means $x<-1$ **or** $x>1$

Comment: In the negative case, the quadratic inequality $(x-1)(x+1)>0$ implies either $x > 1$ or $x < -1$. Draw an upward-opening parabola with two roots $1, -1$ to convince yourself.

Comment: It means ($x-1 > 0$ and $x+1>0$) or ($x-1<0$ and $x+1 < 0$).

Comment: I see! Sorry, for some reason I thought that the way we evaluate this expression is by splitting it into $x-1>0$ and $x+1>0$, which can later be further simplified to $1<x$ and $−1<x$.

Comment: That makes complete sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify, the same will hold for this expression as well $0>(x−1)(x+1)$ --> ($x−1<0$ and $x+1<0$) or ($x−1>0$ and $x+1>0$), right?

Comment: @FlavioEsposito Wrong! $(x-1)(x+1) < 0$ when $(x-1)$ and $(x+1)$ are of opposite signs, so either ($x-1<0$ and $x+1>0$) or ($x-1>0$ and $x+1<0$). Then the second or case is always false, so this reduces to just ($x-1<0$ and $x+1>0$).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to multiply both sides by $x^2$, which is always positive after $x= 0$ is ruled out:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac 1x &> x\\
x &> x^3\\
x^3 - x &< 0\\
x (x+1)(x-1) &< 0
\end{align*}$$

By sketching a cubic curve with positive $x^3$ term and 3 real roots, or by a table like the following, the solution is $x<-1$ or $0<x<1$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
x&(-\infty,-1)&-1&(-1,0)&(0,1)&1&(1,\infty)\\\hline
x+1&-&0&+&+&+&+\\\hline
x&-&-&-&+&+&+\\\hline
x-1&-&-&-&-&0&+\\\hline
x^3-x = x(x+1)(x-1)&-&0&+&-&0&+
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

$ab>0\implies$

Either $a,b>0$

Or $a,b<0$

Do, in the second case, it should be either $x>$ max$(-1,1)$ or $x<$ min$(-1,1)$

Alternatively

$$\dfrac1x>x\iff\dfrac1x-x>0\iff\dfrac{1-x^2}x>0$$

$$\iff x(x+1)(x-1)<0$$

As the product needs to be negative, we need odd number of terms to be $<0$

All the three will be $<0,$ if $x<$min$(-1,0,1)=?$

Only one of them is $<0,$ if $x$ lies between the max and the second max value, exclusive of both i.e., $0<x<1$

Comment: Thanks so much!